# Azure WebApp - Test Hybrid Connection from Kudu Console

Tags: testing, azure-web-app-service, hybrid

I have an Azure web app that has some Hybrid Connections setup.  I'd like to be able to prove they are working from the KuDu cmd interface.

Unfortunately telnet is not installed as part of the Azure WebApp OS (Win Server 2012) and I seem to have limited permissions.

Can anyone help?

Specifically I want to make sure I can relay to an email server, so telnetting to the port would be very useful.

Kind regards
Si

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you try tcpping instead?  tcpping is installed and available for use from the Kudu console.

Comment: Hi,   Yes that worked thank you.  It does tell me there is an issue, I get the following.   **Connection attempt failed: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 192.168.60.20:25**   I am wondering if using this IP address for a hybrid connection is this issue.

Comment: PS  Thanks so much for posting an alternative.

Comment: You will need to use a hostname rather than an IP address - IP addresses in Hybrid Connections are not quite reliable and depend on how the underlying framework is implemented. As for tcpping, it may not work as a proof of concept - there's a local port on the Web App that does the relay, and tcpping will only test connectivity to this port. Hybrid Connections is an application level relay, so only data is really getting transmitted through the pipe (no syn/acks, etc.). We are working on better debugging tools for Hybrid Connections.

Comment: That's great insight thank you.  We're going to try the host name instead of an IP address.  I look forward to better debugging tools, sounds great.

Comment: changing to the host name worked great, all working now!